# Selecting duplicate values from mysql and displaying all of them

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the following SQL query to pull all duplicate values:

```
Select `Racetime`,`Trainer`
from tom_cards
where `Trainer` in (
  select `Trainer`
  FROM tom_cards
  GROUP BY `Racetime`,`Trainer`
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

I want to have something more like

```
Select `Racetime`,`Trainer`
from tom_cards
where `Trainer` and `Racetime in (
  select `Trainer` and `Racetime`
  FROM tom_cards
  GROUP BY `Racetime`,`Trainer`
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

but that's not valid.  What would be a valid query to express the same thing?

Comment: What thing are you trying to express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can concatenate

```
Select Racetime,Trainer from tom_cards 
where concat(Racetime,Trainer) in 
    (select concat(Racetime,Trainer) FROM tom_cards 
         GROUP BY Racetime,Trainer 
           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I handle these situations by doing a group by clause in a sub query and then selecting the rows I want from that.

```
SELECT Racetime, Trainer FROM (
  SELECT Racetime, Trainer, COUNT(*) as occurrences 
  FROM tom_cards
  GROUP BY 1,2
) Racetime_Trainer_counts
WHERE occurrences > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join to a subquery result:

```
SELECT `Racetime`,`Trainer`
FROM tom_cards
  JOIN (
    SELECT `Racetime`,`Trainer`
    FROM tom_cards
    GROUP BY `Racetime`,`Trainer`
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) dupes
    ON tom_cards.Racetime = dupes.Racetime AND tom_cards.Trainer = dupes.Trainer
```

Comment: The aggregate inner query identifies the pairs you want, and joining those to the original table gets you the correct number of occurrences of each pair.